# In Android, how to select a certain bitmap on a SurfaceView?

Tags: android, bitmap, surfaceview

When developing with android, I have several bitmaps on a `surfaceview` : how can I select a certain bitmap with `onTouch` method?

I know the x,y coordinates can be got in onTouch method, but I don't know how to match it with a bitmap.

Should I check all the bitmaps coordinates with the touched `x` and `y`? Or is there a simpler solution?